# Angular UI Grid auto complete bug

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using AngularJs and ui-grid, and in my grid I am using auto-complete within the Name Column; said that ui-grid-cellNav is enabled for cell navigation, my problem is when I am pressing arrow up and down in the auto-complete it's changing the row in the grid, not the auto-complete items:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.cellNav', 'ui.grid.pinning', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', function ($scope, $http, $log) {

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    modifierKeysToMultiSelectCells: true,
    showGridFooter: true
  };
  
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name: 'id', width:'150' },
    { 
      name: 'name',
      width:'200',
      enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
      editableCellTemplate:'<div class="typeaheadcontainer"><input type="text" ' +
                                            'class="typeaheadcontrol"' +
                                            'data-ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" ' +
                                            'data-typeahead="name as states.name for states in grid.appScope.states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" ' +
                                            'data-ng-required="true" ' +
                                            'typeahead-append-to-body="true"'+
                                            'data-typeahead-editable ="false"' +
                                            'ui-grid-editor ui-grid-edit' +
                                            'data-typeahead-on-select="typeaheadSelected(row.entity, $item)" ' +
                                            '/></div>',
    },
    { name: 'age', displayName: 'Age (not focusable)', allowCellFocus : false, width:'100' },
    { name: 'address.city', width:'200' },
    { name: 'phone', width:'150' },
    { name: 'company', width:'150' },
    { name: 'email', width:'150' },
    { name: 'balance', width:'100' },
    { name: 'guid', width:'100' }
  ];

  $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    });

    $scope.info = {};

    $scope.currentFocused = "";

    $scope.getCurrentFocus = function(){
      var rowCol = $scope.gridApi.cellNav.getFocusedCell();
      if(rowCol !== null) {
          $scope.currentFocused = 'Row Id:' + rowCol.row.entity.id + ' col:' + rowCol.col.colDef.name;
      }
    };

    $scope.getCurrentSelection = function() {
      var values = [];
      var currentSelection = $scope.gridApi.cellNav.getCurrentSelection();
      for (var i = 0; i < currentSelection.length; i++) {
        values.push(currentSelection[i].row.entity[currentSelection[i].col.name])
      }
      $scope.printSelection = values.toString();
    };

    $scope.scrollTo = function( rowIndex, colIndex ) {
      $scope.gridApi.core.scrollTo( $scope.gridOptions.data[rowIndex], $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[colIndex]);
    };

    $scope.scrollToFocus = function( rowIndex, colIndex ) {
      $scope.gridApi.cellNav.scrollToFocus( $scope.gridOptions.data[rowIndex], $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[colIndex]);
    };

    $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
       $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
       gridApi.cellNav.on.navigate($scope,function(newRowCol, oldRowCol){
             // var rowCol = {row: newRowCol.row.index, col:newRowCol.col.colDef.name};
             // var msg = 'New RowCol is ' + angular.toJson(rowCol);
             // if(oldRowCol){
             //    rowCol = {row: oldRowCol.row.index, col:oldRowCol.col.colDef.name};
             //    msg += ' Old RowCol is ' + angular.toJson(rowCol);
             // }
              $log.log('navigation event');
            });
    };
    $scope.states = [
              {
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": "Alabama",
                  "abbreviation": "AL"
              },
              {
                  "id": 2,
                  "name": "Alaska",
                  "abbreviation": "AK"
              },
              {
                  "id": 3,
                  "name": "American Samoa",
                  "abbreviation": "AS"
              },
              {
                  "id": 4,
                  "name": "Arizona",
                  "abbreviation": "AZ"
              }];
}]);
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
.printSelection {
    width: 600px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="scrollTo(20,0)">Scroll To Row 20</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="scrollTo(0,7)">Scroll To Balance</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="scrollTo(50,7)">Scroll To Row 50, Balance</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="scrollToFocus(50,7)">Focus Row 50, Balance</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="getCurrentFocus()">Get Current focused cell</button>  <span ng-bind="currentFocused"></span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="getCurrentSelection()">Get Current focused cell values</button>
  <input type="text" ng-model="printSelection" placeholder="Click the 'Get current focused cell values' button to print cell values of selection here" class="printSelection">
  <br>
  <br>
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-pinning ui-grid-edit class="grid"></div>
</div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1tqcB5noOvuwaLEUCDgC?p=preview).

Comment: The ui-grid uses the arrow keys aswell to move from cell to cell. That's why you can't select the typeahead items by arrow keys.

Comment: so is there is any solution for it

Comment: See my answer to your other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829158/angular-ui-grid-autocomplete-with-ui-grid-cellnav